# 2D text to 3d text - Manim

Tags: text, 3d, 2d, manim

is there a way to have a 2d text on screen and then turn it 3D ?
or is there any way of having a 3d text or I can only achieve that by making complex 3d shapes ?
I tried making complex 3d shapes and then positioning the camera so it seems 2D and then rotating the camera to have a smooth transition between 2d and 3d but I don't really rather to create shapes for every letter in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very simple way to load 2d text in a 3d scene: You actually just need to use 1 single command which is:

```
self.add_fixed_in_frame_mobjects()
```

Then you just put your text variable(s) inside the parentheses and you're done.